# Filter Dictionary 'like' string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am building a python script to a vendor API. I am getting the below return in my response body:

```py
[
  {
    "ID": 3189,
    "DefID": 17,
    "Value": "Newspaper",
    "Name": null,
    "ForeignKey": 54245074
  },
  {
    "ID": 3190,
    "DefID": 17,
    "Value": "Newspaper",
    "Name": null,
    "ForeignKey": 604567819
  },
  {
    "ID": 3191,
    "DefID": 18,
    "Value": "TV",
    "Name": null,
    "ForeignKey": 1169994785
  },
  etc.
```

The type is originally `<class bytes>` and I have converted to `<class str>` by using

`data_str = data_bytes.decode('utf-8')`

I have then tried to convert this to a dictionary, but that doesn't work because of the format.

`data_dict = json.loads(data_str)`

**How do I create a dictionary of `ForeignKeys` and their corresponding `Value` by filtering this by `DefID`?**

Example:

```py
#for defID = 17
data_dict17 = {54245074:"Newspaper", 604567819:"Newspaper"}

#for defID = 18
data_dict18 = {1169994785:"TV"}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: ...I don’t see a question here.  Can you clarify please?

Comment: How do I create a dictionary with keys as `ForeignKeys` and values as `Value`, where `DefID` is a specific number, given the above format `str`?

Comment: I think you must continue to try to convert this to a json format, since it's the proper way to do that.

Comment: Please include what you want the output format to be

Comment: Apologies, have changed how I have structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need a groupby `DefID`

```
data = [
  {
    "ID": 3189,
    "DefID": 17,
    "Value": "Newspaper",
    "Name": None,
    "ForeignKey": 54245074
  },
  {
    "ID": 3190,
    "DefID": 17,
    "Value": "Newspaper",
    "Name": None,
    "ForeignKey": 604567819
  },
  {
    "ID": 3191,
    "DefID": 18,
    "Value": "TV",
    "Name": None,
    "ForeignKey": 1169994785
  }
]

res = {}
for i in data:
    res.setdefault(i['DefID'], dict()).update({i["ForeignKey"]: i['Value']})
    #OR
    #res.setdefault(i['DefID'], []).append({i["ForeignKey"]: i['Value']})

print(res[17])  # --> {54245074: 'Newspaper', 604567819: 'Newspaper'}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of having a lot of different variables, it would make sense to put them in a dictionary of their own:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for d in json.loads(data_str):
    data_dict[d['DefID']][d['ForeignKey']] = d['Value']
```

Result:

```
>>> data_dict
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {17: {54245074: 'Newspaper', 604567819: 'Newspaper'}, 18: {1169994785: 'TV'}})
```

If you prefer a regular `dict`, you can use `data_dict = dict(data_dict)` at the end.